# Execute two commands with docker exec

Tags: linux, docker, command, composer-php, exec

I'm trying to do two commands in docker exec. Concretely, I have to run a command inside a specific directory.
I tried this, butit didn't work:

```
docker exec [id] -c 'cd /var/www/project && composer install'
```

Parameter `-c` is not detected.
I also tried this:

```
docker exec [id] cd /var/www/project && composer install
```

But the command `composer install` is executed after the `docker exec` command.
How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try: `docker exec [id] /bin/bash -c 'cd /var/www/project && composer install'`

Comment: thanks dude, i didn't saw your comment but it worked!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In your first example, you are giving the `-c` flag to `docker exec`. That's an easy answer: `docker exec` does not have a `-c` flag.

In your second example, your shell is parsing this into two commands before Docker even sees it. It is equivalent to this:

```sh
if docker exec [id] cd /var/www/project
then
    composer install
fi
```

First, the `docker exec` is run, and if it exits 0 (success), `composer install` will try to run *locally*, outside of Docker.

What you need to do is pass both commands in as a single argument to `docker exec` using a string. Then they will not be interpreted by a shell until already inside the container.

```
docker exec [id] "cd /var/www/project && composer install"
```

However, as you noted in the comments, this also does not work. That's because `cd` is a shell builtin, and doesn't exist on its own. Trying to execute it as the initial command will fail. So the next step is to hand this off to a shell to execute.

```
docker exec [id] "bash -c 'cd /var/www/project && composer install'"
```

And finally, at this point the `&&` has moved into an inner set of quote marks, so we don't really need the quotes around the `bash` command... you can drop them if you prefer.

```
docker exec [id] bash -c 'cd /var/www/project && composer install'
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your command and it's not working, that's the error shown:

rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"cd /var/www/project && composer install\": stat cd /var/www/project && composer install: no such file or directory"

obviously, the directory does exist so i can access manually.

Comment: @Adrià Yes, I hadn't thought about `cd` being the command here. I updated the answer, though it more or less now matches the answer you yourself posted (but with more explanation of why it works).

Answer (score 4):

Everything after the container id is the command to run, so in the first example `-c` isn't an option to exec, but a command docker tries to run and fails since that command doesn't exist.

Most likely you found this syntax from a `docker run` command where the entrypoint was set to `/bin/sh`. However, exec bypasses the entrypoint, so you need to include the full command to run. As others have pointed out, that command includes a shell like bash or in the below example, sh:

```
docker exec [id] /bin/sh -c 'cd /var/www/project && composer install'
```

Answer (score 2):

as Nehal J Wani said in his commentary, the correct syntax is the following:

```
docker exec [id] /bin/bash -c 'cd /var/www/project && composer install'
```

many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are fine if you want to run 2 arbitrary commands. But if the first command is simply `cd`, then you should use the `-w` option to set the working directory instead.

```
docker exec -w {dir} {container} {commands}
```

So in your example:

```
docker exec -w /var/www/project {container} composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add my example here because it is a bit more complex then the ones thate were shown above. This example also illustrates on how to find a container id that should be used in the docker exec command.

I needed to execute a composite docker exec command against docker container over ssh.
I managed to achieve this in 2 steps:

-definition of the variable that contains a command expored as an environment variable

-ssh command that runs it

1. environment varialbe definition:

   export COMMAND="bash -c 'php bin/console --version && composer --version'"
2. ssh command that runs on a remote system:

ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i keyfile.pem ec2-user@111.222.111.222 'docker exec `docker ps|grep php|grep api|grep -v cron|awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"'` '$COMMAND

As you can see I left the command out of the single quotes to pass its actual value to the SSH process

The output of the command execution is:

```
Warning: Permanently added '111.222.111.222' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Symfony 4.3.5 (env: dev, debug: true)
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Composer version 1.9.1 2019-11-01 17:20:17
Connection to 111.222.111.222 closed.
```

If you wish to execute this command in a single line you can use a bit modified version of my first example:

```
COMMAND="bash -c 'php bin/console --version && composer --version'" ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i keyfile.pem ec2-user@111.222.111.222 'docker exec `docker ps|grep php|grep api|grep -v cron|awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"'` '$COMMAND
```